# Find the value $a$ such that the function $y=a(x^2)-5$ satisfies the differential equation $xy'-y+8(x-2)^2 = 37-32x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the value $a$ such that the function$ y=a(x^2)-5$ satisfies the differential equation $xy'-y+8(x-2)^2 = 37-32x$.

I  solved the different equation to $ y = -8x^2-5+Cx$.
How do I get from here to  $y =ax^2 - 5.$
$C$ is not given, so I am confused. Thanks guys!

Comment: $c=0$ and $a=-8$

Comment: Thanks man. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}y&= -8x^2-5+Cx\\ax^2-5&= -8x^2-5+Cx\\x^2(a+8)-Cx&=0\end{align}$$
This is true for all $x$:
$$\implies a+8=0 \text { and } c=0$$

Comment: @JasonQian  You're welcome